# jquery to assign selected property to select element which have value with space or special charcters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to assigning selected property to option element,
Here is html select.

```
<select class="form-control" data-style="btn-primary" id="user_currency" required>
                          <option value="">Select currency</option>
                          <option value="America (United States) Dollars - USD">America (United States) Dollars – USD</option><option value="India Rupees - INR">India Rupees – INR</option></select>
```

Below is jquery to assign selected property,

```
$("#user_currency option[value="+objData.user_currency+"]").prop("selected",true);
```

Now `objData.user_currency` has value of `"India Rupees - INR"`

But i get below message in console and code not working,

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #user_currency option[value=India Rupees - INR]
```

If there is value without spaces or special characters it working fine, but have problem with space or character,
How i do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set value.

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$("#user_currency").val(objData.user_currency);
```

Comment: you are also correct, this also worked for me, seems this is easy.

Comment: @rjcode.. I recommend you to go with easy answer. I just showed what's your mistake. But Satpal's answer shows how it can be achieved easily.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change `"` to `'` in `$('#user_currency...` so that `value` can get its value within `"` as below

```
$('#user_currency option[value="'+objData.user_currency+'"]').prop("selected",true);
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie.. I just changed `"` to `'` in `$('#user_currency...` so that `value` can get its value within `"` :)

Comment: Don't explain it to me... explain it to everyone else :)